# POS tagging using RNN

Tags: python, nlp, tensorflow, theano, deep-learning

I implemented a POS tagger using RNN. There are 3 features, if current word is W_i:

- Feature 1: W_i-2, W_i-1, W_i, W_i+1, W_i+2
- Feature 2: suffix of Feature 1, 2 characters
- Feature 3: [If W_i is all uppercase, If W_i is all lowercase, If
  first character of W_i is uppercase]

In my model, I have two RNNs, for Feature 1 and Feature 2, then the outputs of the RNNs and Feature 3 are concatenated, following with a softmax. The RNN for Feature 1 is bidirectional.

I tried my model on PennTree Bank, but the accuracy is very low (<50% on both training and evaluation). Just wondering, if anyone know an open source POS tagger using RNN (word based feature) in python that I can compare it with my model, then I can find if there is a bug in my code or simply because this model is not working.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you investigate this https://spacy.io/blog/part-of-speech-pos-tagger-in-python

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff, Thanks for the link. I can see it has very good performance on the WSJ data set. However, it uses perceptron, and I am looking for a deep learning RNN approach implementation. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

There is one that is implemented using a bi-directional LSTM and CRF. It can be found [here.](https://github.com/glample/tagger)